# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.xxxxx/com.xxxxx.MapsActivity}:

Tags: java, android, google-maps

App is crashing when I click on back button on Map activity.
Adding moveTaskToBack(true); in onBackPressed() not worked. 
Below is the logcat:

--------- beginning of crash

```
2020-02-06 10:12:44.807 26120-26120/com.xxxx.user E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.xxxx.user, PID: 26120
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.xxxx.user/com.xxxx.user.MapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bt.s()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4663)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4681)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap6(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1777)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:232)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6802)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1103)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bt.s()' on a null object reference
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.cv.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@20142051@20.1.42 (040408-0):27)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@20142051@20.1.42 (040408-0):30)
        at cm.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@20142051@20.1.42 (040408-0):5)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:504)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.zzb(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzj.onDestroyView(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza.onDestroyView(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onDestroyView(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onDestroyView(Unknown Source)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performDestroyView(Fragment.java:2811)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:954)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2659)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchDestroy(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2644)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchDestroy(FragmentController.java:329)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy(FragmentActivity.java:366)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onDestroy(AppCompatActivity.java:233)
        at com.xxxx.user.MapsActivity.onDestroy(MapsActivity.java:250)
        at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:7183)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4650)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4681)
```

Comment: show your `activity`.

Comment: interface is null, initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that you are just attempting to call a method to an interface or object that is not initialized on line 250:

> com.xxxx.user.MapsActivity.onDestroy(MapsActivity.java:250)

Comment: on (MapsActivity.java:250) is super.onDestroy();

Full code
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        mWebView.onDestroy();
        mapFragment.onDestroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }